# how do i view generated javascript from typescript in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

As I understand typescript gets converted to javascript. I have a file MyTypeScript.ts in a webstorm project. I want to be able to see my generated javascript. How do I do this in Webstorm?

Answer (score 3):

Set up a [file watcher](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/file-watchers-in-webstormphpstorm-6-a-k-a-background-tasks/) and you'll see both the `.ts` and `.js` files in the project view.

Answer (score 2):

Install TypeScript with npm if you haven't done so already: `npm install -g typescript`

Once that is done, go into WebStorm preferences, navigate to File Watchers and set up a new TypeScript watch. The program field is the path to your installed TypeScript.